# Visual Studio 2012 - how to step into (F11) source code

Tags: c#

I can't **step into(F11)** the source code. The effect of pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> is same like the effect of pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>.Only when I set a break point in the function where I want to step into I can enter the source code of function. The problem starts after I installed the plug-in in Visual Studio 2012. The plug-in is **.net reflector visual studio extension**. Who can answer my doubts?

Comment: Try to add an Breakpoint inside that code where you want to go with F11. Also check plugin keyboard(keys bindings) and check visual studio keyboard

Comment: The other root cause is when something messed up your build settings and sources don't match referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

You can check and change your keyboard setting and key-bindings under TOOLS -> Options. Search for *stepin* like this:

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt that OP first changed the shortcut, and then forgot about it.

Comment: He might have if an extension (or plugin) offered to change them for him. Resharper has examples of this, allowing you to choose between using resharper shortcuts and visual studio shortcuts when there may be conflicts

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the cause of problem, it is that when you installed .net reflector visual studio extension on Visual Studio, the Plug-in will Turn OFF the "Enable Just My Code" setting on startup. That's the reason why I can't step into(<kbd>F11</kbd>) the source code of some Function(such as I use Aop of Spring.Net to log some information). Below is the picture which can make you a glance.[image]

[image]