# Step Into (F11) doesn’t enter some functions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Inａprogram downloaded from [Normal Estimation Using Integral Images](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.php#normal-estimation-using-integral-images). I would like to step into `computeFeature (output)`.
[image]

The program will not step into the function. Neither press F11 nor set a breakpoint at some line inside the function definition. But the program will step into the next statement `deinitCompute()`.

The method mentioned in [Why Visual Studio's debug mode Step Into (F11) sometimes doesn't enter inside some functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065735/why-visual-studios-debug-mode-step-into-f11-sometimes-doesnt-enter-inside-so) did not work.
My Visual Studio 2015 Options setting is like below.
[image]

The method mentioned in [Step into not working, but can force stepping after some asm steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249235/step-into-not-working-but-can-force-stepping-after-some-asm-steps) did not work either. My Visual Studio 2015 clien Property Pages setting is like below.
 [image]

The method mentioned in [Visual Studio 2012 - how to step into (F11) source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947442/visual-studio-2012-how-to-step-into-f11-source-code) did not work either.
The F11 in my Visual Studio 2015 is OK.
[image]

This problem could repeat in a different computer.
How could I get Visual Studio to step directly into the function computeFeature (output)?

Here are the source code **[Normal Estimation Using Integral Images](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.php#normal-estimation-using-integral-images)** and the associative test data file **[table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd](https://github.com/otherlab/pcl/blob/master/test/table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd)**.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.23107.0 D 14REL, on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Not quite clear from your question, but if you're trying to step into a function of a precompiled library that you don't have source code or debugging information for, chances are that it simply won't work unless you're in assembly view already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some reasons for VS not stepping into a function:
1) There is no debug information for the function.
   In this case, you may need to set up VS to step into assembly language.

2) The debug information for the file containing the function is damaged.
   Recompile the file in debug mode.

3) The function is in a library and has no debug information.

4) The function is an operating system function and has no debug information.

5) You are running in release mode.

6) The function has no code and has been eliminated.
   This could happen depending on your optimization settings.

7) The compiler converted your function into "inline" code (via optimizations).

Comment: According to your checklist, I find my problem lies in the 3rd item. After I delete the library and add the corresponding source code, I can step into the function finally. Thank you very much.

Comment: How do I instruct it to step into a function? I have the sources for the library, but it doesn't ask me for their location, like it usually does.

Comment: You press `F11` to step into a function.  See reasons above to explain why VS debugger won't step into a function.

Comment: @TangoXiao library should be compiled with debug information generated, i.e. with .pdb file and source code available for VS to actually see the other code. MS actually even provide .pdb files for their own run-time for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Matthews has stated most of the cases.

However, in my case, it's because the function I was trying to *step into* was actually a **generator**.

I *called* the generator just like I usually do to void functions. Because C# generators are lazy, they wouldn't execute the function before we trigger it.